# how to export dump file for oracle10g I tried in the following way SQL> expdp dump dumfile=filename.dmp

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I tried to dump but I am getting a error in SQL command prompt.

How to export dump file for oracle10g I tried in the follwing way:
`SQL> expdp dump dumfile=filename.dmp`

Comment: Are you missing a 'p' in 'dumpfile=filename.dmp"?

Comment: it is an typo error. this is the text i typed in SQL prompt    SQL> expdp dump dumpfile=filename.dmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expdp` is an operating system command, not an SQL command. You need to run it from an operating system command prompt.

There is more information [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#i1012781), including descriptions of the command parameters (and as noted it is `dumpfile` rather than `dumfile`), and [they provide examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#i1006376).

If you haven't used it before, be aware that the dump file is created on the server in a location identified by the `directory` parameter, which is set to the [name of a *database* directory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm#i1009520) object - not to a directory path you'd recognise. This is quite different from the old `exp` command.

The minimum would be something like:

```
expdp <user>/<password> DIRECTORY=<directory> DUMPFILE=<filename>.dmp
```

... with your own sensible values for the `<>` placeholders. But investigate all the options to make sure you export what you need. It rather depends why you're doing the export, and what you'll do with the dump file later, I suppose...

Comment: thanks Alex...I remember that I exported .DMP  file few months ago using SQL prompt after connecting.  i think now I am missing some  syntax in the command  given above.

Comment: @Mahesh - I guess you *might* have done it via a SQL*Plus `host` command, but I'm not sure why you'd do that rather than just using the command line.