# Exporting user to dmp file in Oracle11gr2

Tags: oracle, export, oracle11gr2

I am trying to create a dump file of an Oracle database on 11g

the user is CONTACT and lets say pwd is zip (lowercase)

i log into SQLplus using run command "sqlplus /nolog"

and then

Connect sys/pwd@oracle11g as sysdba

then i try to run my export command

```
SQL> exp sys/pwd owner=CONTACT DIRECT=Y FILE=E:\ORA_DUMP\CONTACT.dmp LOG=E:\ORA_DUMP\CONTACT.log
```

and then i hit enter but i get

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "exp sys/pw....." -rest of line ignored

i tried

```
SQL> exp CONTACT/zip owner=CONTACT DIRECT=Y FILE=E:\ORA_DUMP\CONTACT.dmp LOG=E:\ORA_DUMP\CONTACT.log
```

but i get same error

what am i doing wrong

Comment: You might have an easier time finding an answer for this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19279263/266304); but is there a reason you're using the original export tool rather than the newer data pump (`expdp`)?

Answer (score 9):

`exp` is an application, not a SQL statement.  You would invoke it from the operating system command line, not from within SQL*Plus.  Well, I suppose you could invoke it from within SQL*Plus since SQL*Plus can call client-side operating system utilities, it just wouldn't make a great deal of sense to do so.

Run the `exp` command from your shell (or from a DOS command-line in Windows).  You'll almost certainly want the script to specify the TNS alias (i.e. `exp contact/zip@tns_alias ...`) since you aren't connected to a database when you're at the command line.